# Mismatch column name in report viewer and PDF export?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, ssrs-tablix

I have text box in the header and populated dynamically.
If my query result is more than 1 page, when i go to next page, the column value will change but when i export it to PDF or Word, only the column value of the first page will appear.

Please see image below:
http://s2.postimg.org/3q81agpyh/Cropper_Capture_26.jpg

What's wrong here?